# Ansible 2.0 parsing Json and store in another variable

Tags: json, parsing, ubuntu, ansible, openstack

My Task is

```
  - name: task name
    shell: some command --format json
    register: result
```

The output will be in below json format

```
[
  {
    "mac_address": "x.x.x.x.x.x",
    "fixed_ips": "{\"subnet_id\": \"s-s-s-s\",\"ip_address\": \"172.*.*.*\"}",
    "id": "1",
    "name": ""
  },
  {
    "mac_address": "x.x.x.x",
    "fixed_ips": "{\"subnet_id\": \"s-s-s-s\", \"ip_address\": \"192.*.*.*\"}",
    "id": "2",
    "name": ""
  }
]
```

What i want to do is,get only the ip address that starts with 192 and store it into a variable so that i can use it in another task.

Comment: post ur full json

Comment: pasted full json as you requested

Answer (score 2):

If it is a list of dicts, use `selectattr`:

```
"{{ (result.stdout | from_json | selectattr('ip_address','match','^192') | list | fist).ip_address }}"
```

I assume that you need only one element, so I use `first` to get single element from the list.

Updated expression due to modifications of input data:

```
- set_fact:
    ip_address: "{{ ( result.stdout |
                      from_json | 
                      map(attribute='fixed_ips') |
                      map('from_json') |
                      selectattr('ip_address','match','^192') |
                      list |
                      first
                    ).ip_address }}"
```

`fixed_ips` is a string, so you need to apply `from_json` with `map` to convert every item to be able to apply `selectattr` filter.

Comment: Hi posted full json.

Comment: Hi Im new to this, so please explain more. What is this .ip_address in last?Are we storing it in a variable?

Comment: I updated my answer one more time to be complete playbook snippet where you get new fact (variable) `ip_address`.

Comment: Thanks. Now i need to check connectivity to that ip. is there any way to ICMP ping that ip and check connectivity ?